# Changing client name and application name in BigblueButton

Tags: nginx, bigbluebutton

I have setup BigBlueButton on my server and its working as intended. I want to change the name of the client more suitable to my liking instead of Bigbluebutton.html (just html file will do as swf will be hosted in html)
I tried changing in `/etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/client_dev` 
`location /client/bigbluebutton.html` to `location /client/collab.html`

But the join meeting still redirects to Bigbluebutton.html
How can i change the client name and reference it properly in API's too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the BigBlueButton Frequently Asked Questions:

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/support/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-client-bigbluebutton-html-portion-of-the-url